# where does value get stored after onchange in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I want to do a drop down list and when I click the submit button, it posts back the selected value.

I don't know if I'm doing it right but I've searched around and came up with this so far.

I just want to know if I'm doing it right and where it would store the value once it posts back.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DisplayName("Name:")<br />
    @Html.TextBox("NAME")<br />

    @Html.DisplayName("Password:")<br />
    @Html.TextBox("PASS")<br />

    @Html.DisplayName("Team Name:")<br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Teams, new SelectList(Model.Teams, "value", "TeamNAME"), new {onchange = "submit()"})

    <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
}
```

Want to get the value here

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            //GET VALUE OF THE SELECTED TEAM HERE
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks pretty close -- the only thing is that, you should be consistent in using the model-bound HTML helper methods, or not.  That is, use `TextBoxFor` and `DropDownListFor`, or `TextBox` and `DropDownList`, but don't mix and match.

If you use the model-bound ones, then you should be able to simply add the model type as a parameter to your postback action:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel postback)
```

For the unbound ones, you can add parameters individually using their names:

```
public ActionResult Index(string NAME, string PASS, string TEAM)
```

(assuming you'd change to `@Html.DropDownList("TEAM", new SelectList(Model.Teams, "value", "TeamNAME"), new {onchange = "submit()"})`)

Answer (score 1):

**Details:** The below is assuming you are using a Model called Team and that you are using that Model in the View. (code not tested)

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("Teams", String.Empty)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Teams = new SelectList(db.Team, "TeamId", "TeamNAME");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Team team)
{
    // Here is your selected Team id
    //team.TeamId

    return View();
}
```

Check out this Tutorial for more info on using the DropDownList

[MVC 4 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)

Comment: Thank you, I used the above answer but it's pretty much the same thing.